# SQL Server Row_Number() with Group By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The View in SQL Server 2008 has a Group By and it refines the records to 23.  The same query in a ROW_Number sproc returns 58 records.  I have tried various combininations of Partitions to return the same result, have tried all fields (like the View) or other pairings but nothing works.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

The Stored Procedure that doesn't group correctly (returns 58 records).  @Filter contains johndoe, just like the View (see below):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Reporting2]
@OutTotalRecCount INT OUTPUT, 
@CurrentPage INT, 
@PageSize INT, 
@SortDirection INT,
@SortField nvarchar(50),
@Filter nvarchar(50) 
AS     
SELECT *
FROM          
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY 
    --dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID, 
    --dbo.ppoma_fsa.OTYPE, 
    --dbo.ppoma_fsa.STEXT, 
    --dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW,
    --dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID, 
    dbo.ppoma_us_bp.Personal_No, 
    dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID, 
    dbo.ppoma_us_bp.BP, 
    dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_FIRST, 
    dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_LAST

    --dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID, 
    --dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW

    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortField = 1 THEN ppoma_fsa.OBJID END DESC,  
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortField = 2 THEN ppoma_fsa.OTYPE END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortField = 2 THEN ppoma_fsa.OTYPE END DESC   
    ) 
    AS Row,

dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID as _OBJID, 
dbo.ppoma_fsa.OTYPE as _OTYPE, 
dbo.ppoma_fsa.STEXT as _STEXT, 
dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW,
dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID AS Depot_BP, 
dbo.ppoma_us_bp.Personal_No, 
dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID, 
dbo.ppoma_us_bp.BP, 
dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_FIRST, 
dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_LAST

FROM         dbo.ppoma_assigned INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_us_bp ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID = dbo.ppoma_us_bp.OBJID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_fsa ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.OBJID = dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID
WHERE     (dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID LIKE N'%' + @Filter + '%') AND (NOT (dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW = 'Service'))

)

AS TeamWithRowNumbers 
WHERE  Row >= (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND Row <= @CurrentPage*@PageSize     


SELECT @OutTotalRecCount = COUNT(*)

FROM         dbo.ppoma_assigned INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_us_bp ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID = dbo.ppoma_us_bp.OBJID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_fsa ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.OBJID = dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID
WHERE     (dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID LIKE N'%' + @Filter + '%') AND (NOT (dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW = 'Service'))
```

The View with Group By that returns 23 records:

```
SELECT     dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID, dbo.ppoma_fsa.OTYPE, dbo.ppoma_fsa.STEXT, dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW, dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID AS Depot_BP, 
                      dbo.ppoma_us_bp.Personal_No, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.BP, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_FIRST, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_LAST
FROM         dbo.ppoma_assigned INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_fsa ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.OBJID = dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ppoma_us_bp ON dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID = dbo.ppoma_us_bp.OBJID
GROUP BY dbo.ppoma_fsa.OBJID, dbo.ppoma_fsa.OTYPE, dbo.ppoma_fsa.STEXT, dbo.ppoma_fsa.LOW, dbo.ppoma_assigned.SOBID, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.Personal_No, 
                      dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.BP, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_FIRST, dbo.ppoma_us_bp.NAME_LAST
HAVING      (dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID = 'johndoe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any sample data it's impossible to say for certain.

It could be because the proc is using a `LIKE` on the filter parameter, and the view uses `=`.

Stored Proc:

```
WHERE     (dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID LIKE N'%' + @Filter + '%')
```

View:

```
HAVING      (dbo.ppoma_us_bp.UserID = 'johndoe')
```

Also, given that the view is using GROUP BY, it very likely would return fewer rows, if there are any duplicates in the data. The ROW_NUMBER function is in no way like GROUP BY, they don't do the same thing at all.

GROUP BY is for aggregating, usually in order to do a SUM or other aggregate function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

ROW_NUMBER is just for assigning a sequential number to rows in the result set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

What I don't understand is, if you want the same results as the view, why not just select from it?

Comment: you can't pass values to a view, something I need to do dynamically from my web app.  I need the row number which allows me to isolate records in the grid on the server.  The Having in the view works because you can add group by fields which works but you can't use Having and Group By in a Row_Number result...this is why I tried a Partition.

Comment: Of course you can't pass parameters to a view, you'd normally specify them in a where clause when you select from the view. e.g. `SELECT * FROM myView WHERE whatever = 'xyz'`. Why don't you just do that? You don't need to put parameters in the HAVING clause as in your example.

Comment: The select returns all records, there is no grouping.  Need to have the grouping.

Comment: OK I really don't understand what you mean now... what select? In the view or the proc? Please clarify your question, it's very hard to understand what you need.

Comment: I want the same results as the View but in a Row_Number() query.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert the View to a Make Table (ppoma_final) and then modified the Row_Number() to the following.  Works like a charm.

```
SELECT *
FROM          
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (

    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortField = 1 THEN ppoma_final.OBJID END DESC,    
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortField = 2 THEN ppoma_final.OTYPE END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortField = 2 THEN ppoma_final.OTYPE END DESC 
    ) 
    AS Row,

    [OBJID]
    ,[OTYPE]
    ,[STEXT]
    ,[LOW]
    ,[Depot_BP]
    ,[Personal_No]
    ,[UserID]
    ,[BP]
    ,[NAME_FIRST]
    ,[NAME_LAST]
    ,[id_fsa]
    ,[id_us_bp]



FROM         dbo.ppoma_final
WHERE     (dbo.ppoma_final.UserID LIKE N'%' + @Filter + '%') AND (NOT (dbo.ppoma_final.LOW = 'Service'))

)

AS TeamWithRowNumbers 
WHERE  Row >= (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND Row <= @CurrentPage*@PageSize     


SELECT @OutTotalRecCount = COUNT(*)

FROM         dbo.ppoma_final
WHERE     (dbo.ppoma_final.UserID LIKE N'%' + @Filter + '%') AND (NOT (dbo.ppoma_final.LOW = 'Service'))
```

Comment: Great, glad you've solved your problem. Next time - ask the duck! http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/